# How do I install Chocolatey using C#?

Tags: c#, chocolatey

I tried running the command-line instructions from the website

```
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))*
```

In a pipeline

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

// create a pipeline and feed it the script text
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(commandToRun);
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

// close the runspace
runspace.Close();
```

And by invoking a process

```
Process.Start("@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command \"iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))\" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\\chocolatey\\bin")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CInstInst
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string command = @"@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ""iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin";
           ExecuteCommandSync(command);
        }

        public static void ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
        {
            try
            {
                // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
                // and "/c " as the parameters.
                // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows,
                // and then exit.
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

                // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
                // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                // Do not create the black window.
                procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                proc.Start();
                // Get the output into a string
                string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                // Display the command output.
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (Exception objException)
            {
                // Log the exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Via this article.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C)

You can verify the install here: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey or by running cinst.  If you already have it installed simply rename this to chocolatey.old, which will allow you to test.  When you're done - delete the new "chocolatey" folder and rename your "chocolatey.old" folder back.

Answer (score 0):

Install Chocolatey Software:

```
private async Task ChocolateyDownload(string software)
{
    await RunCommandHidden("cd \"C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\"\nchoco.exe install " + software + " -y");
}
```

Usage: await ChocolateyDownload(your software name without choco install);

Get Chocolatey:

```
 private async Task InstallChocolatey()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey"))
            {
                await RunCommandHidden(
                    "@\"%SystemRoot%\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command \" [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))\" && SET \"PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\\chocolatey\\bin\"");
            }
        }
```

Usage: await InstallChocolatey();

Run Command Hidden Function:

```
private bool Exit = false;
        public async Task RunCommandHidden(string Command)
        {
            Random dew = new Random();
            int hui = dew.Next(0000, 9999);
            string[] CommandChut = { Command };
            File.WriteAllLines(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Documents\\RunCommand" + hui + ".bat", CommandChut);
            Process C = new Process();
            C.StartInfo.FileName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Documents\\RunCommand" + hui + ".bat";
            C.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            C.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            C.Exited += C_Exited;
            C.Start();
            while (Exit == false)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10);
            }

            Exit = false;
            File.Delete(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Documents\\RunCommand" + hui + ".bat");
        }

        private void C_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exit = true;
        }
```